# What kind of JavaScript function is <object>.toJSON(....)? Why does it influence the object without direct calling?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm beginner at JS and I've recently came across this code.
How is it possible that the function influenced the outcome? 
The next thing I don't quite get is that the function is just defined, it is directly called ( pet.toJSON() <<< Something like this ). So how is it possible that it works? And the last thing I'd like to ask: What is the name of that function or what should I look for on web to learn that.
I'm sorry if it is something obvious but your answer would help me a lot.
Have a nice day!

```
const pet = {
  name: 'Marek'
}

pet.toJSON = function () {

  return {}
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(pet))   // the result is {}



userSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    const user = this
    const userObject = user.toObject()

    delete userObject.password
    delete userObject.tokens

    return userObject
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What kind of JavaScript function is `<object>.<somefunction>`?

A perfectly normal method.

> Why does it influence the object without direct calling?

It is directly called, just by code you didn't write and aren't looking at.

The internals of `JSON.stringify` check for a method called `toJSON` on objects and calls it if it exists.

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If the value has a toJSON() method, it's responsible to define what data will be serialized.

Or [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify) (and more specifically [this part of it](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-serializejsonproperty)):

> - Let toJSON be Get(value, "toJSON").
> - ReturnIfAbrupt(toJSON).
> - If IsCallable(toJSON) is true
>
>   - Let value be Call(toJSON, value, «key»).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you often use it? Or where is it really useful. But thanks a lot for that first answer again.

Comment: I've never used it. I can think of a few hypotheticals (avoiding cyclical data structures and converting a data structure that is useful internally to one that is required by another service).

Comment: Thanks. Umm... The last question.... delete is accessible on in this function isn't it? Otherwise, in normal function it would not work properly. At least that's what I think. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I am sorry for not attaching the code. I haven't noticed that, but now it should be at the bottom of my question (userSchema,......)